# Why I'm getting null?

Tags: unity, c#

Not what is null but why I'm getting it if I'm adding first the LineRenderer component ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Apply these values in the editor
    public Transform target;

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        // set the color of the line
        lineRenderer.startColor = Color.red;
        lineRenderer.endColor = Color.red;

        // set width of the renderer
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;

        // set the position
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, target.position);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The null exception is on the line :

```
lineRenderer.gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

Before adding the linerenderer component I tried to use the attribute :

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
```

And then tried to get it as compoment in the Start but also it gave me null exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
lineRenderer.gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

You haven't assigned a value to `lineRenderer`, so it's still null and you can't access its `gameObject` property.

Do this:

```
lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

Note that you do not need the `GetComponent<>()` line at all.